# Mapdeck Geojson Data Cannot be Styled

Tags: r, shiny, gis, styling, mapdeck

I want to create a r shiny dashboard using mapdeck package displaying the many layers of geojson in one map. But i have a problem, whenever I add styling into my geojson the R always crashes and nothing shown in my map.
the memory also always high if i add a styling. But if i dont add any styling to my geojson data, the code works okay, but the display is just basic purple, i want to change the style according my clasification but it always crash. My data is not large, the "pwr.geojson" is only 600KB and the "point_sma.geojson" is only 30KB. I think it's because an infinite loop while rendering the style. Maybe anyone can answer what is wrong with the code or maybe another solution to stop the infinite loop?

here I provide the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(sf)
library(mapdeck)

#geojson for the main map
pwr <- sf::st_read("data/purworejo.geojson")
pointsma_pwr <- sf::st_read("data/point_sma.geojson")

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader( #the header )
dashboardSidebar(#the sidebar )
dashboardBody(
tabItem(tabName = "viz",
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Peta Preferensi Pemilih Pemula",
                    status = "primary",
                    width = 9,
                    height = "auto",
                    h2("Peta Preferensi Pemilih Pemula Pemilu 2024"),
                    mapdeckOutput("map", height = "800px")
                )
              )
      )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 #access token mapbox
  key <- "MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"
 #rendering mapdeck
  output$map <- renderMapdeck({
    mapdeck(
      token = key,
      zoom = 10,
      location = c(109.9989, -7.6965),
      style = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11'
    ) %>% 
      add_geojson(
        data = pwr,
        layer_id = "pwr-id",
        update_view = F
      ) %>%
      add_geojson(
        data = pointsma_pwr,
        layer_id = "pointsma-id",
        update_view = F
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I try to add styling to the geojson for example like this

```
add_geojson(
data = pwr,
layer_id = "pwr-id",
update_view = F,
fill_colour = "green" #this is the styling i want to change
)
```

whenever i add the styling, the r always crashes, i expected the geojson will change the colour into green.

here I provide the console log:

```
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'jsonify':
  method     from    
  print.json jsonlite
```

it stops like that, and i supposed it's because of the infinite loop that happen while i add any styling. I also provide the memory change if i add the styling [this is the increased memory if i ad the styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmxLg.png)

Comment: Can you make your exmple small and reproducible? Start by removing all the shiny code and just supply a `mapdeck() %>% add_geojson()` example that recreates your issue.

Comment: and use a publicly available data set, for exmple the one supplied with mapdeck `mapdeck::geojson`